# R fpp package, ARIMA prediction interval using bootstrap

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I need to compute prediction intervals for a model which residuals aren't normally distributed.
In "fpp" package forecast() function on Arima and arima objects enables using bootstrap to estimate prediction intervals.
I use following code for model generation and obtaining prediction:

```
test_model <- Arima(h02_train, order = c(3,1,3)
                  , seasonal =list(order = c(2,1,1), period=12)
                  , include.mean = F, lambda = NULL)
test_pred <- forecast(test_model, h=12, level=95, bootstrap = T, npaths=1000)
```

I receive a following error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(level, "%", sep = "")) : 
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

I've tried arima, Arima and auto.arima objects, different npaths also tried updated package "fpp2" each time same error.

Comment: That's a bug that occurs when level has only one value. Remove the level argument and it works fine. I'll fix it in the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. In case anyone faces the same problem and doesn't want to compute 2 different prediction intervals (eg to plot efficiently only one interval) as workaround  level=c(95,95) works.